Adjusting Path Planning Origin in ROS2 Nav2 for a Long Vehicle
I am working with ROS2 Nav2 and the SMAC planner for a long vehicle (a truck), where the planning origin’s traditional placement at the geometric center (base_link) causes some practical issues in navigation. Specifically, the visual and operational path planning starts from the middle of the truck and not from the cabin, which is the operational front.
Here are the details:
Vehicle Length: Approx. 10 meters
Current Planning Frame: base_link (center)
Desired Planning Frame: Front of the cabin, approx. 5 meters ahead of the current frame
I have successfully implemented a custom goal checker plugin that considers the goal reached when the cabin, rather than the midpoint, reaches a target. However, now I am looking to adjust where the path planning begins to reflect the front of the cabin as well.
Questions:

Is there a recommended approach within the Nav2 framework to shift
the planning origin to a different point of the vehicle, such as the
cabin? Is something already embedded in nav2 for easy usage?
Would modifying the SMAC planner or adding a virtual link in
the URDF for the planning origin be advisable?
Are there potential implications for obstacle avoidance or path efficiency that I
should consider with such a modification?

I’m attaching relevant images and configurations to illustrate the current setup and desired changes. Any guidance or suggestions from Steve Macenski or the trajectory planning community, especially on best practices for handling such cases in Nav2, would be greatly appreciated!
Custom Plugin: Video Behavior : Moiving goal checker from center of base_link to the end of Truck's cabin
A) Current Behavior

The Global Path is planned from the middle of the truck (center of base_link)
B) Desired Behavior (If Kinematically Feasible and Not contraindicated)

Global Path Planned From End of Cabin
Thanks in advance!

Ok, I have fixed This issue by generating a new plugin, which I called FrontCabinGoalChecker. Now the behavior of the goal checker is compatible with a nonholonomic robot (Truck, cars, etc) in contrast to the default nav2 goal checker, suitable for circular robots.
The video of the solution is in the following link:
Custom Goal Checker
The plugin code is below if someone needs it:
#include "nav2_core/goal_checker.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "angles/angles.h"
#include "tf2/LinearMath/Quaternion.h"
#include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp"

class FrontCabinGoalChecker : public nav2_core::GoalChecker
{
public:
    void initialize(
      const rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode::WeakPtr& parent,
      const std::string& plugin_name,
      std::shared_ptr<nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS> /* costmap_ros */) override
    {
        auto node = parent.lock();
        if (!node) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to lock weak_ptr during goal checker initialization!");
        }

        node->get_parameter_or(plugin_name + ".xy_goal_tolerance", xy_goal_tolerance_, 1.5);
        node->get_parameter_or(plugin_name + ".yaw_goal_tolerance", yaw_goal_tolerance_, 0.25);
        node->get_parameter_or(plugin_name + ".front_offset", front_offset_, 5.0);

        RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Loaded xy_goal_tolerance: %f", xy_goal_tolerance_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Loaded yaw_goal_tolerance: %f", yaw_goal_tolerance_);
        RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Loaded front_offset: %f", front_offset_);
    }

    void reset() override
    {
        // Reset any internal state if necessary
    }

    bool isGoalReached(
      const geometry_msgs::msg::Pose& query_pose,
      const geometry_msgs::msg::Pose& goal_pose,
      const geometry_msgs::msg::Twist& /* velocity */) override
    {
        double dx = query_pose.position.x + front_offset_ * cos(tf2::getYaw(query_pose.orientation)) - goal_pose.position.x;
        double dy = query_pose.position.y + front_offset_ * sin(tf2::getYaw(query_pose.orientation)) - goal_pose.position.y;
        double distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        double dyaw = angles::shortest_angular_distance(
          tf2::getYaw(query_pose.orientation),
          tf2::getYaw(goal_pose.orientation));

        return distance <= xy_goal_tolerance_ && fabs(dyaw) <= yaw_goal_tolerance_;
    }

    bool getTolerances(geometry_msgs::msg::Pose& pose, geometry_msgs::msg::Twist& twist) override
    {
        pose.position.x = xy_goal_tolerance_;
        pose.position.y = xy_goal_tolerance_;
        pose.position.z = 0.0; // Not used
        pose.orientation = tf2::toMsg(tf2::Quaternion(tf2::Vector3(0, 0, 1), yaw_goal_tolerance_));

        twist.linear.x = 0.0; // Not used
        twist.angular.z = 0.0; // Not used
        return true;
    }

private:
    double front_offset_;
    double xy_goal_tolerance_;
    double yaw_goal_tolerance_;
};

#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(FrontCabinGoalChecker, nav2_core::GoalChecker)

Just adjust the front_offset value for your vehicle's dimension, in my case the truck is 10 meters length, then I used 5 meters offset from its geometric center (where standard goal checker was using).

what would be the difference between doing that and creating a new link at that offset and setting that as the robot_base_frame? Of course having published the tf between that link and the base_link. Regards

probably any difference, in engineering there are a lot of ways to fix the same issue. Someones are better than others. Maybe your approach can indeed work better and be easier to implement. Thanks for the comment.
